# Is it possible to convert xls file to xlsx with Microsoft Graph Excel APIs?

Tags: excel, xls, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

My story shortly. I have a system that sends Excel Binary (xls) files to my email (Office 365) and finally they get saved to my OneDrive for Business account. So, the next step I do really want to do is to put them to PowerBI for analysis.

But there is a problem. They seems to be corrupted at the source and cannot be processed correctly by PowerBI Desktop (missed columns). Experimenting I've found that if they are opened and resaved by Excel Desktop they get fixed and works fine. The same is true for Excel Online in Office 365 (if they are converted to OpenXML (xlsx) format). I need this conversion to be made without human intervention so I'm hope for a way to make it with Microsoft Graph Excel APIs.

So, I wonder if it possible to convert xls file to xlsx using Microsoft Graph somehow.

PS. It looks like Excel Interop on server is the only option I have right now, but I do not like it. And I tried Excel Data Reader library, but it returns empty dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look possible within Graph itself. Accessing a workbook of an xls file at the moment returns an error:

`"error": {
        "code": "AccessDenied",
        "message": "Could not obtain a WAC access token.",`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried and know about it. But there is an internal API (seen through F12 tools), that converts xls to xlsx in Excel Online. Speaking honestly, I just do not want to believe that interop is the only option in my case...

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to use ".xls" files using Microsoft Graph endpoint. The file should be of open XML format (xlsx).